# How to use OnSelectedChange event on JqueryMultiColumn?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I use jquerymulticolumn in ASP.NET project.How i can do Postback in my multicolumn combobox selectedchange event.When i clicked a item on combobox, i set it to my hiddenfield.And i want to send it to code behind.

aspx:

```
.
.
<td>

   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="HiddenAksiyonId" />

   <div id="datatable">
       <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th><th>Action Name</th><th>Action ID</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <asp:repeater id="rep" runat="server">
               <itemtemplate>
                  <tr>
                     <td><%#Eval("AKSIYON_ID")%></td><td><%#Eval("AKSIYON_ADI")%></td><td><%#Eval("AKSIYON_ID")%></td>
                   </tr>
               </itemtemplate>
             </asp:repeater>
          </table>
      </div>

   </td>
   .
   . 
     <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#datatable").multicolselect({
          buttonImage: "../Images/selectbutton.gif",
          valueCol: 1,
          hideCol: 0
      });

      </script>
```